# Запятая в выражении "то справа, то слева"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Как при помощи справочника Розенталя объяснить постановку запятой в выражении "то справа, то слева"?

> Изредка откуда-то из-под моих ног ТО СПРАВА, ТО СЛЕВА вспархивали какие-то птички, наперебой высоко вспрыгивали кузнечики.

Comment: Надо взять справочник Розенталя и прочитать нужную тему   Решение для союза ТО...ТО дается однозначное, вариантов нет, так в чем же  тут трудность? http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

[§ 13. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)

> Между *однородными членами* предложения, соединенными повторяющимися
>   союзами и…и, да…да, ни…ни, или…или, либо…либо, **то…то**, не то…не то и
>   др., ставится запятая:
>   *Дорога **то** проваливалась между горных гребней,
>   **то** поднималась на округлые холмы (Леон.)*